# Problemas na comunicação com o webService disponibilizado pelo governo

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, api

Estou com um problema na comunicação com o webService do eSocial, meu certificado está correto, porém ainda não consegue estabelecer uma conexão segura, apresenta a seguinte mensagem: "Erro ao fazer a solicitação HTTP para https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?wsdl. Isso pode estar relacionado ao fato de o certificado de servidor não estar corretamente configurado com HTTP.SYS no caso HTTPS. Isso também pode ter sido causado por uma incompatibilidade da associação de segurança entre o cliente e o servidor."

[image: Imagem da Exception no visual studio]

Comment: Voce está autenticado? Eu nao sei que tipo de autenticacao o servico do governo usa, mas muito provavelmente terá que fazer um pedido antes com uma chave fornecida por eles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel, creio que você não tenha conseguido acessar o serviço porque a URL que você está usando está incorreta. Quando você adiciona o parâmetro *?wsdl* no final da URL do serviço, você está solicitando o WSDL do serviço do eSocial, que é o *contrato* do serviço. Ou seja, essa URL que você postou seria a que você usaria para adicionar a referência ao serviço dentro do Visual Studio, e a mesma URL **sem** o parâmetro *?wsdl* seria a que você usaria para acessar o serviço de fato.

Então, para acessar o serviço, a URL deve ser essa:

> https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc

Além disso, de acordo com o Manual de Orientação do Desenvolvedor do eSocial v1.6.3, página 83, item '7.9. Certificação digital', também é necessário instalar na máquina que vai acessar o serviço a **Cadeia de Certificados emitida em 06/02/2017** pelo Serpro, que são 3 certificados que podem ser obtidos nesse endereço:

> https://certificados.serpro.gov.br/serproacf/certificate-chain

Segundo o item **02.03** da página de Perguntas Frequentes do Portal do eSocial, os certificados devem ser instalados na ordem que estão dispostos nessa página do Serpro, e:
*A Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5 deve ser instalada no repositório de AC raiz. A Autoridade Certificadora SERPRO v4 e Autoridade Certificadora do SERPRO Final v5 devem ser instaladas no repositório de AC intermediária.*

Lembrando que também é necessário ter instalado no computador que vai acessar o web service um certificado digital válido (A1 ou A3, e-CNPJ ou e-CPF), que deve ser usado para acessar o serviço. Uma dica: Quando comecei os testes com o eSocial, fiquei quase uma semana batendo a cabeça para conseguir o primeiro acesso, quando finalmente descobri que, no meu caso (e-CNPJ A1), era necessário selecionar a opção **Marcar esta chave como exportável** (*Mark this key as exportable*) e instalar meu certificado no repositório (*store*) **Pessoal** (*Personal*), do **Usuário Atual** (*Current User*).

Em relação ao código usado para acessar o serviço (não sei se você já está fazendo assim, porque você não postou nenhum trecho do código), você deve configurar o **binding** do serviço (eu usei `BasicHttpBinding` ou `BasicHttpsBinding`) para usar *SecurityMode = Transport* (para o HTTPS) e *ClientCredentialType = Certificate* (para especificar um certificado), mais ou menos assim:

```
 var urlServicoEnvio = @"https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc";
 var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServicoEnvio);
 var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();  //Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.5
 // ou:
 //var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

 var wsClient = new WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient(binding, address);
 wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Cert;

 var retornoEnvioXElement = wsClient.EnviarLoteEventos(loteEventosXDoc.Root);
 wsClient.Close();
```

Quanto à classe `WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient` usada no código, ela foi criada pelo Visual Studio ao adicionar uma *Service Reference*, usando uma URL parecida com a que você tentou usar para acessar o serviço (com a diferença que usei o parâmetro *?singleWsdl* ao invés de *?wsdl*):

> https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl

No VS também é possível adicionar uma referência ao serviço usando diretamente o arquivo *WsEnviarLoteEventos-v1_1_0.wsdl* disponibilizado no **Pacote de Comunicação do eSocial** (última versão 1.4.1), que se encontra na página da documentação técnica do Portal do eSocial.

Essa ferramenta, *Add Service Reference* do VS, criará uma classe cliente para consumir o serviço na web, no caso do exemplo `WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient`, que herda a classe *System.ServiceModel.ClientBase*.

Também é possível usar a ferramenta de linha de comando **svcutil.exe**, que, da mesma forma, criará uma classe cliente herdando a classe *System.ServiceModel.ClientBase*. Alternativamente também é possível usar a ferramenta de linha de comando **wsdl.exe**, mais antiga, para serviços da época do .NET Framework 2, baseados em ASMX, que também criará uma classe cliente, mas dessa vez herdando a classe *System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol*. Mas nesse caso o código para consumir o serviço seria um pouco diferente.

Seguindo todos esses passos, o acesso ao web service do eSocial deve funcionar.

Comment: Sua resposta falta elementos. Este link pode ficar indisponível no futuro. É interessante, além do link, você postar essas dicas que você citou na sua resposta.

Comment: Andrei, a primeira parte da minha mensagem responde a pergunta, o Gabriel estava usando a URL errada para acessar o serviço. O link que postei é um extra, para ajudar pessoas que caiam aqui nesse post e tenham dúvidas em como conectar ao web service do eSocial. Eu não reescrevi as dicas do link porque a pergunta original já estava respondida na minha mensagem, e eu criei a página de dicas justamente para não precisar ficar escrevendo as mesmas coisas repetidamente (antes de criar a página eu escrevi as mesmas dicas diversas vezes em fóruns de discussão sobre o eSocial).

Comment: Somente quem deu os negativos saberia explicar os motivos, mas talvez por você passar perto do problema e no final a solução está em um link, fica sendo uma resposta meio que genérica e não específica para a pergunta em questão. Além do mais essa resposta está identica a essa outra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277472/3117

Comment: Math, Mas a solução final **não está** no link... Como eu expliquei para o Andrei, a solução **está** na mensagem. A URL usada pelo Gabriel para acessar o serviço está errada, a URL que ele usou é para adicionar uma referência ao serviço e não para acessar o serviço, e eu expliquei isso na minha resposta, e não no link. O link foi só um extra com mais informações sobre esse assunto, caso alguém precise no futuro. E, a minha resposta ao Gabriel foi idêntica à resposta para o Glauco porque as perguntas eram idênticas também. Nesse caso eu deveria somente postar o link da outra pergunta similar?

Comment: Realmente, a resposta está no seu texto. Sobre as perguntas duplicadas, pode votar para encerrá-la indicando a sua respectiva duplicata. Sobre os negativos, sempre é de ajuda quando quem votou justifica  mas não temos como saber se isso vai realmente acontecer