# Erro comunicação https com WebService

Tags: c#, api

Estou com um problema na comunicação com o **webService** do **eSocial**, meu certificado está correto, porém, ainda não consegue estabelecer uma conexão segura, apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

> Erro ao fazer a solicitação HTTP para https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?wsdl. Isso pode estar relacionado ao fato de o certificado de servidor não estar corretamente configurado com HTTP.SYS no caso HTTPS. Isso também pode ter sido causado por uma incompatibilidade da associação de segurança entre o cliente e o servidor.

Answer (score 3):

Encontrei a solução. Basta adicionar o protocolo de segurança a ser utilizado.

Fazer o import: `using System.Net;`

E adicionar o código antes do request:

```
// No caso do eSocial é o Tls11
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

Comment: Foi o que funcionou pra mim, boa garouto!

Answer (score 0):

Glauco, sua pergunta é idêntica à essa pergunta do Gabriel Rech:

> [Problemas na comunicação com o webService disponibilizado pelo governo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239342/86952)

Portanto, replicarei aqui a mesma resposta que escrevi lá, para o Gabriel, com algumas pequenas alterações.

Creio que você não tenha conseguido acessar o serviço porque a URL que você está usando está incorreta. Quando você adiciona o parâmetro *?wsdl* no final da URL do serviço, você está solicitando o WSDL do serviço do eSocial, que é o *contrato* do serviço. Ou seja, essa URL que você postou seria a que você usaria para adicionar a referência ao serviço dentro do Visual Studio, e a mesma URL **sem** o parâmetro *?wsdl* seria a que você usaria para acessar o serviço de fato.

Então, para acessar o serviço, a URL deve ser essa:

> https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc

Além disso, de acordo com o Manual de Orientação do Desenvolvedor do eSocial v1.6.3, página 83, item '7.9. Certificação digital', também é necessário instalar na máquina que vai acessar o serviço a **Cadeia de Certificados emitida em 06/02/2017** pelo Serpro, que são 3 certificados que podem ser obtidos nesse endereço:

> https://certificados.serpro.gov.br/serproacf/certificate-chain

Segundo o item **02.03** da página de Perguntas Frequentes do Portal do eSocial, os certificados devem ser instalados na ordem que estão dispostos nessa página do Serpro, e:
*A Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5 deve ser instalada no repositório de AC raiz. A Autoridade Certificadora SERPRO v4 e Autoridade Certificadora do SERPRO Final v5 devem ser instaladas no repositório de AC intermediária.*

Lembrando que também é necessário ter instalado no computador que vai acessar o web service um certificado digital válido (A1 ou A3, e-CNPJ ou e-CPF), que deve ser usado para acessar o serviço. Uma dica: Quando comecei os testes com o eSocial, fiquei quase uma semana batendo a cabeça para conseguir o primeiro acesso, quando finalmente descobri que, no meu caso (e-CNPJ A1), era necessário selecionar a opção **Marcar esta chave como exportável** (*Mark this key as exportable*) e instalar meu certificado no repositório (*store*) **Pessoal** (*Personal*), do **Usuário Atual** (*Current User*).

Em relação ao código usado para acessar o serviço, você deve configurar o **binding** do serviço (eu usei `BasicHttpBinding` ou `BasicHttpsBinding`) para usar *SecurityMode = Transport* (para o HTTPS) e *ClientCredentialType = Certificate* (para especificar um certificado), mais ou menos assim:

```
 var urlServicoEnvio = @"https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc";
 var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServicoEnvio);
 var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();  //Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.5
 // ou:
 //var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

 var wsClient = new WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient(binding, address);
 wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Cert;

 var retornoEnvioXElement = wsClient.EnviarLoteEventos(loteEventosXDoc.Root);
 wsClient.Close();
```

Se você fizer assim, não há necessidade de informar o protocolo como sendo o TLS 1.1 (eu também tentei dessa forma na época que não estava conseguindo acessar o serviço e depois vi que não era necessário, mas, se não estou enganado, eu tinha chegado à conclusão de que o protocolo necessário era o TLS 1.2, ao invés do TLS 1.1).

Quanto à classe `WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient` usada no código, ela foi criada pelo Visual Studio ao adicionar uma *Service Reference*, usando uma URL parecida com a que você tentou usar para acessar o serviço (com a diferença que usei o parâmetro *?singleWsdl* ao invés de *?wsdl*):

> https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl

No VS também é possível adicionar uma referência ao serviço usando diretamente o arquivo *WsEnviarLoteEventos-v1_1_0.wsdl* disponibilizado no **Pacote de Comunicação do eSocial** (última versão 1.4.1), que se encontra na página da documentação técnica do Portal do eSocial.

Essa ferramenta, *Add Service Reference* do VS, criará uma classe cliente para consumir o serviço na web, no caso do exemplo `WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient`, que herda a classe *System.ServiceModel.ClientBase*.

Também é possível usar a ferramenta de linha de comando **svcutil.exe**, que, da mesma forma, criará uma classe cliente herdando a classe *System.ServiceModel.ClientBase*. Alternativamente também é possível usar a ferramenta de linha de comando **wsdl.exe**, mais antiga, para serviços da época do .NET Framework 2, baseados em ASMX, que também criará uma classe cliente, mas dessa vez herdando a classe *System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol*. Mas nesse caso o código para consumir o serviço seria um pouco diferente.

Seguindo todos esses passos, o acesso ao web service do eSocial deve funcionar.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/153942)

Comment: Leandro, você já acessou o web service do eSocial? O que responderia a pergunta, então? Porque, se a pergunta está dizendo que está dando erro ao acessar o web service, e a URL que está sendo usada está errada, se eu aponto para a URL correta, para que a conexão com o web service funcione, não consigo ver onde minha mensagem não responde a pergunta! E outro moderador, o Math, me orientou a colocar um link para essa outra pergunta similar, que eu já tinha respondido. O que posso está fazendo de tão errado assim, que todo mundo fica negativando minhas respostas aqui no StackOverflow Português?

Comment: @PedroGasparLoboFX, a questão é não apresentar o conteúdo relevante no corpo da resposta, se o conteúdo está disposto em um link externo, como na sua resposta da outra pergunta. Isso torna a resposta "frágil", porque não existe nenhuma garantia de que esse conteúdo estará disponível no futuro ou que contenha a mesma informação presente hoje. E "Já existe uma pergunta..." não é uma resposta e sim uma sinalização de possível duplicata.

Comment: Pois é, mas antes essa resposta **não era** um link para outra resposta, eu tinha replicado exatamente o mesmo texto da outra resposta aqui, que ao meu ver era uma possível resposta à pergunta original, e poderia ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema, mas, fui negativado, e o moderador Math, nesse outro post similar, disse que eu já tinha dado uma resposta idêntica aqui e sugeriu que eu colocasse um link de duplicata.... Foi o que eu fiz, e agora você está me dizendo qu eu não deveria fazer isso.

Comment: Fechei a outra como duplicada dessa

Comment: Dei +1 a resposta pois acredito que ela esteja melhor formulada agora. No antigo post, você inseriu um comentário, e não uma resposta. Isso tornou a resposta com uma qualidade muito baixa. Infelizmente você adquiriu algumas negativações nesse tempo. Mas esta resposta, do jeito que está, é de grande importância para SO.

Comment: Obrigado pelos "puxões de orelha" de ontem, a todos vocës, acho que contribuíram para eu gastar um tempo e escrever respostas bem melhores, de fato!