# CommunicationException: Erro no cliente ao fazer a solicitação HTTP (HTTP.SYS) a WebService de terceiros

Tags: c#, wcf, api

Estou desenvolvendo para o **eSocial** há mais de um ano já, e, estou encontrando o seguinte erro em alguns clientes, ao tentar fazer envio ao serviço:

> **System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException**:
>   *Erro ao fazer a solicitação HTTP para https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc. Isso pode estar relacionado ao fato de o certificado de servidor não estar corretamente configurado com HTTP.SYS no caso HTTPS. Isso também pode ter sido causado por uma incompatibilidade da associação de segurança entre o cliente e o servidor.*
>
> ---> **System.Net.WebException**: *A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um envio.*
>       ---> **System.IO.IOException**: *Não é possível ler os dados da conexão de transporte: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto.*
>         ---> **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException**: *Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto em System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)...*

Na maioria dos computadores o programa está funcionando perfeitamente, só em alguns computadores esse problema acontece. Minha plataforma alvo é o .NET Framework 4.7.

Eu mesmo já respondi duas perguntas sobre esse erro aqui no SO:

> (1) [Problemas na comunicação com o webService disponibilizado pelo governo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239342/86952)
>   (2) [Erro comunicação https com WebService](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264097/86952)

E, pelas pesquisas que eu fiz, há duas soluções para o problema:

1. Configurar a propriedade `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33084791/8133067);
2. Instalar as atualizações do Windows Update (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45494549).

No caso da primeira solução: O serviço do eSocial usa o protocolo de segurança **TLS 1.2**, mas nem sempre essa é a configuração padrão da máquina. Eu já fiz isso no código e **não** resolveu na maioria dos casos:

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

No caso da segunda solução: Nas pesquisas que fiz o problema podia acontecer em computadores com Windows 7 desatualizado, e teoricamente a atualização via Windows Update resolveria, mas, na maioria dos casos não resolveu, e já peguei até alguns casos desse erro no Windows 10.

Eu até fiz um programa de testes, com o [log de mensagens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/message-logging/) e o [log de *trace*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/) ligados, para ver se eu conseguia mais alguma informação, mas, a única coisa diferente que descobri (por causa do *tracing*) é que o erro ocorre quando a mensagem é enviada pelo canal (de comunicação com o WebService).

Segue o código que estou usando para instanciar e chamar o serviço:

```
 const string UrlSvcBase = @"https://webservices.{0}.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/{1}";
 string urlServico = String.Format(UrlSvcBase, "producaorestrita", @"enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc");

 var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServico);
 //var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
 var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();  //Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.5
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
 // Manual de Orientação do Desenvolvedor v1.4, página 39, item '5.4.5. Validações aplicadas':
 // "O tamanho limite da mensagem SOAP é 750 kbytes."
 // O valor padrão da propriedade MaxReceivedMessageSize é 65.536,
 // que é alterado então para 750 KB * 1024 = 768.000 bytes.
 // Caso contrário, ocorre a exceção:
 //   Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
 //   InnerException: System.Exception {System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException}
 //   "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded.
 //    To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element."  
 //   HResult: -2146233087 (0x80131501)
 binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 768000;

 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

 var wsClient = new WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient(binding, address);
 // Variável 'certificado' é do tipo X509Certificate2.
 wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificado;

 wsClient.Open();
 // Variavel 'lote' é do tipo XElement.
 var retorno = wsClient.EnviarLoteEventos(lote);
 wsClient.Close();
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode causar esse erro, ou alguma ideia do que mais posso fazer para tentar descobrir a causa do problema?

Comment: Boa tarde Pedro, também estou nesse projeto e estamos utilizando o .Tls.
Realizei um teste agora e não houve nenhum problema no envio, já tentou utilizar ele ? Ambientes testados: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Oi Felippe, sim, fiz um teste ontem mesmo usando as opções *Tls | Tls11 | Tls12* e também não funcionou...

Comment: Editei a pergunta para incluir as novas opções que tentei na propriedade *ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol*.

Comment: como está a sua references do ServicoEnviarLoteEventos ?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a pergunta Felippe. Você quer saber como está o código que instancia e chama o serviço? Eu instancio um objeto da classe `ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient`, passando o binding HTTPS e a URL, informo o certificado digital para conexão e então chamo o método `EnviarLoteEventos()` do objeto, passando o lote XML como argumento. Vou atualizar a pergunta para incluir o código também.

Comment: Existem algumas diferenças entre nossas implementações, na parte de configuração de url e de certificado.
Url eu popula no próprio ServicoEnviarLoteEventos, uma classe que tem na classe References.cs
Certificado também no próprio ServicoEnviarLoteEventos

Comment: Você poderia informar onde você leu que a versão do tls do servidor do eSocial é 1.2? Pois eu não encontrei isso nos manuais..

Comment: Aparentemente existe um bug no .Net, que ele não faz o fallback para as versões anteriores quando uma versão não é suportada. Experimente colocar manualmente a versão 1.0 e verifique se funciona. Eu inspecionei o pacote com o fiddler, o sistema deveria emitir 3 requisições de handshake em caso de erro, uma para cada versão, mas isso não está ocorrendo, na primeira com falha já estoura a exceção.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound, no manual do desenvolvedor realmente não está especificada versão, apenas diz que o serviço usa a tecnologia TLS. Eu cheguei à conclusão que era a versão 1.2 porque se você acessar a URL do serviço usando o IE, clicar com o botão direito do mouse sobre a página e clicar em Propriedades, vai aparecer a informação *Connection: TLS 1.2*; e também se você rodar um teste nesse site aqui: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br, o resultado dirá que o serviço está configurado para os protocolos TLS 1.0, 1.1 e 1.2!

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound, mas eu acho que você estava certo! Eu fiz um teste no cliente que estava com esse problema, informando apenas o protocolo TLS 1.0 e nenhum mais: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;`, e funcionou!!! Se você escrever esse seu comentário em forma de resposta ficarei feliz em marca-la como resposta e como (muito) útil! Muito obrigado! Eu já estava há semanas me batendo com esse problema, e tinha até usado o Wireshark, mas não tinha chegado a conclusão nenhuma...

Comment: Estive estudando um pouco mais e aparentemente esse controle de fallback precisa de uma flag TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV, acontece que essa flag introduz um problema de segurança e por isso os servidores não a habilitam. Intuitivamente, acredito que é por isso que o .Net não testa as outras versões. Creio que deve ser feito manualmente como o amigo que postou a resposta ai em baixo.

Comment: Se você quiser estudar um pouco mais a respeito e postar uma resposta detalhada para ajudar a comunidade, segue alguns materiais interessantes: [rfc7507](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7507) e [outra questão do cryptoexchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/how-does-tls-fallback-scsv-help) e [rfc5246](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#appendix-E)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme o comentário do @EProgrammerNotFound, parece ser um bug do .NET. Comigo acontecia a mesma coisa ao transmitir o E-Financeira ao Webservice SPED em algumas máquinas Windows 7 e Windows 2008.

Acabei criando uma rotina quecria uma Stack com os protocolos que quero utilizar (TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1. e TLS 1.2). Em seguida vou desempilhando e atribuindo um protocolo por vez e vou tentando enviar. Se falhar, passo para o próximo protocolo:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType) 0;    

// Pilha com protocolos que vou utilizar
Stack<SecurityProtocolType> protocolosDisponiveis = new Stack<SecurityProtocolType>();
protocolosDisponiveis.Push(SecurityProtocolType.Tls);
protocolosDisponiveis.Push((SecurityProtocolType)768); // TLS 1.1
protocolosDisponiveis.Push((SecurityProtocolType)3072); // TLS 1.2.
var TentarNovamente = false;

do
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = this.protocolosDisponiveis.Pop();

    try
    {
        // Tenta chamar o serviço se der certo ok eu saio fora
        ChamarServico();
        TentarNovamente = false;
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ex)
    {
        TentarNovamente = true;

    }
}
while(TentarNovamente && protocolosDisponiveis.Count() > 0);
```

Comment: Legal Jonas, eu até pensei em fazer algo parecido, mas, devido à falta de tempo acabei, pelo menos por enquanto, só usando o TLS 1.0 sempre mesmo. Mas acho que vou fazer algo parecido com o que você fez, valeu! Eu só não entendi porque você remove todos os protocolos no início do código, um a um... não seria melhor ter feito `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault` (*SystemDefault = 0*)? Dentro do loop, no caso de falha eu também faria a mesma coisa, já que só o protocolo atual estará presente na propriedade `SecurityProtocol`.

Comment: Também, como sugestão para deixar o seu código mais didático para quem possa parar aqui nesse post, você podia acrescentar uma linha do tipo `ChamarServico()` lá no bloco `Try`, para ficar bem claro que é ali que o serviço será chamado.

Comment: Boa, Pedro! Vou seguir a dica e testar o comportamento. O tempo e prazo legal não permitiram que estudasse melhor as possibilidades. A ideia original em remover os protocolos atribuídos por padrão na máquina era evitar que o .NET tentasse estabelecer a conexão usando algum destes. Mas você tem razão. Obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade, agora pensando, você não precisaria remover nem usando uma linha só, como eu sugeri, porque em cada iteração do loop você já joga um único protocolo na propriedade `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`, então isso por si só já remove todos os outros! Aproveitando, deixa eu te perguntar, na versão do .NET que você está usando o enum `SecurityProtocolType` ainda não tinha os valores `SecurityProtocolType.Tls11` e `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`?

Comment: Boa, Pedro. Testei aqui e funcionou seguindo a tua sugestão. Alterei o código exemplo acima. Sobre a versão do .NET, utilizamos o 4.0. E realmente ainda não possui as enumerações. Obrigado pelas dicas.