# Problema de envio do EFD-Reinf (SPED)

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou com um problema no envio do EFD-Reinf, quando tento transmitir tenho o retorno do webservice da seguinte mensagem:

> A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um envio. ---> System.IO.IOException: Não é possível ler os dados da conexão de transporte: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto.

Neste momento:

```
WebResponse webresponse = request.GetResponse();
```

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: seu código ? se colocar um exemplo podemos testar tambem

Comment: Luiz, você instalou a cadeia de certificados do Serpro nessa máquina? Acabei de ver que no manual do desenvolvedor do EFD-REINF não tem esse procedimento, mas no do eSocial, que é muito parecido, tem. E você está informando um certificado digital para fazer a conexão? Veja essa resposta (sobre eSocial, mas serve para o EFD-REINF também): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277471/86952

Comment: Pedro nesta maquina eu transmito o NF-e as cadeias estão instaladas, e o certificado que estou usando pra assinar o xml do reinf é o e-cnpj.

Comment: Tentei transmitir hoje de novo, para ver se é o webservice que esta com problema, e esta ocorrendo a mesma falha.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema Luiz?